# Non-Working WPF Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, inheritance

I am a WPF noob and i hope to stop being so one day (Lol)

Anyways, i am having issues binding a DataTable (Obtained from an OleDBDataAdapter) to a DataGrid. Even though the DataTable is NOT empty, i get nothing on the DataGrid, it only works if i manually setup the ItemsSource property in code-behind. Help? [I want to make this automatic so any changes made to the grid are reflected into the DataTable, enabling me to just use OleDBCommandbuilder to update the Access database itself (Yes, i am lazy :)). I was thinking of extending DataTable to implement INotifyCollectionChanged but im not sure if that's do-able :S]

XAML:

```
            <Grid>
                <DataGrid Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="ListaArticulos" 
                          Padding="-5,0,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Articulos}">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Width="Auto" Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nombre Articulo" Binding="{Binding Nombre}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Categoria" Binding="{Binding Categoria}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Valor" Binding="{Binding Valor}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Cantidad" Binding="{Binding Cantidad}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Color" Binding="{Binding Color}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Material" Binding="{Binding Material}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Referencia" Binding="{Binding Referencia}" Width="*"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </Grid>
```

Code-Behind:

```
    public DataTable _Articulos = new DataTable();

    public DataTable Articulos { get { return _Articulos; } }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ListaArticulos.DataContext = this;
        ReadDB();
    }
```

ReadDB() updates the Articulos DB.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have managed to make a DataTable class that implements INotifyChanged adding a call to the PropertyChangedEventHandler on each of its events related to rows, yet again, i get nothing on the initial datagrid... why?

Comment: DataContext should implement the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface if needed, not the ItemsSource.

Comment: @So my window has to implement that interface? (Even tho i gave up on DataTable, im designing a custom class that will wrap DB data with a ObservableCollection)

Comment: Not the window directly, you could create a class that servers as a datacontext (Often referred as a ViewModel). You should study MVVM to learn how to organize the different kind of objects you will be using with wpf. It`s not a direct answer to your particular problem, but it will pay in the long term. You could start with this article : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

Comment: @Matthieu Thanks, will read, need to know how to organize my code in better ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code

```
    InitializeComponent();
    ListaArticulos.DataContext = this;
    ReadDB();
```

change to

```
    ReadDB();
    InitializeComponent();
```